# Social icon commands like size, alignment and list-style not having any effect in the footer

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position and re-size my social icon links in the footer, however, none of the commands seem to be having an effect, especially when I try to re-size them. I've tried marking the width and height as '!important' but that had no effect either.

Here is a JSFiddle of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/yx9fzxj0/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
    <div id="socialicons">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/PucvPiN.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.vimeo.com"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/FbCckg5.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.footer {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.75;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#socialicons {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 50px;
    list-style: none;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues you have got:

1. `bottom`, `left`, `right` - These three do not work without `position: absolute`. Remove them.
2. Remove the `list-style` by using `none` and add it for the `<li>` mainly.
3. Set the `width` **or** `height` alone for the `<img />`.

```css
.footer {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.75;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}

#socialicons {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

#socialicons li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

#socialicons li img {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div id="socialicons">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/PucvPiN.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.vimeo.com"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/FbCckg5.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh Thank you! That works, now I see where I went wrong. What about making space between the icons? :)

Comment: Thanks, and no problem :)

Comment: @Filip Enjoy your day.